# Internet explorer issue, IE shows all visible content for a split second after AutoPostBack

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer

In ASP.NET 4.5 I use from the AjaxControlToolkit the AutoCompleteExtender.
I also use input fields like the DropDownList, which are set to AutoPostBack=True

All works fine in Firefox, Chrome, except in IE browsers. When an autopostback occurs for a split second the user is able to see all the content which is normally hidden (with CSS or JavaScript). For example you see the the DIV element used for the results of the AutoCompleteExtender for a short period of time. After the page is reloaded everything looks fine again.

Part of the code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf_street" ClientIDMode="Static" OnValueChanged="hf_street_ValueChanged" runat="server" />
<asp:textbox id="tb_street" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" />
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender   
    ID="ace_street"
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList2"
    EnableCaching="false"
    OnClientItemSelected="ace2_ClientItemSelected" 
    CompletionSetCount="10" CompletionInterval="100" 
    CompletionListElementID="div_street" 
    CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
    CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
    CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
    TargetControlID="tb_street" MinimumPrefixLength="1"
    UseContextKey="True" FirstRowSelected="false" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is happening because the CSS that hides the content is being delivered with the content.  You may be witnessing IE interpret the CSS for a split second. If you move the CSS that is responsible for hiding this content to the page instead of the partial chunk of HTML, it may work better.

Comment: Could you post the content that is being loaded dynamically?  Is it possible that it includes styles that cause this blip?